# Python 3.6 merge dictionaries fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to merge two dictionaries, after searching for a close question on stack overflow, I found the next solution:

```
mergeDicts = {**dict1, **dict2}
```

but that doesn't work. While I know my code is alright as I observe right results for single dictionary, once I merge I don't get right results

```
def readFiles(path1):
    // count words


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = readFiles('C:/University/learnPy/dir')
    b = readFiles('C:/Users/user/Anaconda3/dir')
    bigdict = {**a, **b}
    print(a['wee'])
    print(b['wee'])
    print(bigdict['wee'])
```

In `a` there's 1 `.txt` file containing `2 wee`

In `b` there's 1 `.txt` file containing `1 wee`

So I'd expect bigdict output to be 3, but what I observe is bigdict is just getting the numbers of the first dict. `{**dict1 (THIS ONE), **dict2}` and the merge is not working.

Question: what went wrong ? why is this failing on python 3.6 when answers stated it should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dict(**x, **y)` is [doing what its supposed to do](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/). Creates `bigdict` by overwriting values of 1st arg with the 2nd arg. You will need to sum the values by your self.

You can use a `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter
a = {'wee':1, 'woo':2 }
b = {'wee':10, 'woo': 20 }
bigdict = dict(Counter(a)+Counter(b))

Out[23]: {'wee': 11, 'woo': 22}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer + link. Helped a lot.